# C# получить ID обновлённой записи в MS ACCESS

Tags: c#, access, ms-access

Нужно в приложении на c# получить ID только что обновлённой записи в MS Access, т.к. потом этот ID будет использоваться в других таблицах. БД создана в MS Access 2007. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
string root_query = "UPDATE root_tasks SET s_process_time=@s_process_time, s_time_left=@s_time_left OUTPUT INSERTED.ID WHERE s_task_name=@s_task_name";
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
                    {
                        new OleDbParameter("@s_process_time", time),
                        new OleDbParameter("@s_time_left", time_left),
                        new OleDbParameter("@s_task_name", node.Name)
                    });
int root_id = 0;
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        root_id = (int)reader["ID"];
    }
}
```

Но при попытке выполнить запрос вылетает исключение

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса '@s_time_left OUTPUT INSERTED.ID'.

Подскажите, что не так в синтаксисе запроса и как это исправть?

Comment: Что мешает сделать доп. запрос чтоб получить этот ID?

Comment: Это был мой план Б на случай если нет более простого пути (сделать всё одним запросом). Наверное, так и буду делать.